# Se puede simplificar la condicion?

Tags: javascript

quería saber si se puede simplificar un poco la condición del if, ya que es un poco molesto

```
const campos = {
  nombre: false,
  apellidos: false,
  email: false,
  textarea: false,
  usuario: false,
  password1: false,
  telefono: false
};
```

```
formulario.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if (campos.nombre && campos.apellidos && campos.email && campos.textarea || campos.usuario && campos.password1 && campos.telefono && campos.nombre && campos.apellidos && campos.email) {
    formulario.reset();
    alert('formulario enviado');
  } else {
    alert('completa todos los campos');
  }
});
```

Agradeceria una rapida solucion, gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Según entiendo, todos tienen que ser `true`. Se puede verificar que exista al menos un `false` usando `.some()`:

```js
const campos = {
  nombre: false,
  apellidos: true,
  email: true,
  textarea: true,
  usuario: true,
  password1: true,
  telefono: true
};

if (!Object.values(campos).some(e => !e)) {

  console.log("todos son true");

} else {

  console.log("al menos un false");
}
```

Comment: No, el caso es que tengo varios formulario que validar y lo que necesito es que si todos los campos del formulario en el que estoy son iguales a true, entonces se ejecute el codigo.

Comment: Bueno, pero es lo mismo que decir que si al menos uno es `false` que no se ejecute el código, el único caso contrario es que todos sean `true`.

Comment: O más simple: `Object.values(campos).every(e => e)`. Según [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#descripci%C3%B3n), devolverá `false` automáticamente si alguno no cumple la condición. Por lo que no hay desperdicio y no necesitas negar la condición. Aunque también podrías intercambiar las instrucciones de ambos casos.

Comment: También es posible, pero `.some` deja de iterar cuando hay una coincidencia, `every` si o si recorre todos los elementos. Para arrays no exageradamente largos sería lo mismo a nivel práctico. Pero para arrays largos convendría `.some`